# Python - Twisted : POST in a form

Tags: python, parsing, post, twisted, beautifulsoup

**Hi Guys !**

I'm still discovering Twisted and I've made this script to parse the content of HTML table into excel. This script is working well ! My question is how can I do the same, for only one webpage (http://bandscore.ielts.org/) but with a lot of POST requests to be able to fetch all the results, parse it with beautifulSoup and then put them into excel ?

Parsing the source and putting it into excel is O.K, but I don't know how to do a POST request with Twisted in order to implement that in

This is the script I use for parsing (with Twisted) a lot of different pages
(I want to be able to write the same script, but with a lot of different POST data on the same page and not a lot of pages):

```
from twisted.web import client
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
import time
import xlwt

start = time.time()
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet("BULATS_IA_PARSED")
global x
x = 0
Countries_List = ['Afghanistan','Armenia','Brazil','Argentina','Armenia','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Belgium','Belize','Bolivia','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Brazil','Brunei Darussalam','Bulgaria','Cameroon','Canada','Central African Republic','Chile','China','Colombia','Costa Rica','Croatia','Cuba','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Denmark','Dominican Republic','Ecuador','Egypt','Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Faroe Islands','Fiji','Finland','France','French Polynesia','Georgia','Germany','Gibraltar','Greece','Grenada','Hong Kong','Hungary','Iceland','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Ireland','Israel','Italy','Jamaica','Japan','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Kenya','Kuwait','Latvia','Lebanon','Libya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macau','Macedonia','Malaysia','Maldives','Malta','Mexico','Monaco','Montenegro','Morocco','Mozambique','Myanmar (Burma)','Nepal','Netherlands','New Caledonia','New Zealand','Nigeria','Norway','Oman','Pakistan','Palestine','Papua New Guinea','Paraguay','Peru','Philippines','Poland','Portugal','Qatar','Romania','Russia','Saudi Arabia','Serbia','Singapore','Slovakia','Slovenia','South Africa','South Korea','Spain','Sri Lanka','Sweden','Switzerland','Syria','Taiwan','Thailand','Trinadad and Tobago','Tunisia','Turkey','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','Uruguay','Uzbekistan','Venezuela','Vietnam']
urls = ["http://www.cambridgeesol.org/institutions/results.php?region=%s&type=&BULATS=on" % Countries for Countries in Countries_List]


def finish(results):
    global x
    for result in results:
        print 'GOT PAGE', len(result), 'bytes'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result)
        tableau = soup.findAll('table')
    try:
        rows = tableau[3].findAll('tr')
        print("Fetching")
        for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        y = 0
        x = x + 1
        for td in cols:
            texte_bu = td.text
            texte_bu = texte_bu.encode('utf-8')
            #print("Writing...")
                    #print texte_bu
            ws.write(x,y,td.text)
            y = y + 1
    except(IndexError):
        print("No IA for this country")
        pass

    reactor.stop()

waiting = [client.getPage(url) for url in urls]
defer.gatherResults(waiting).addCallback(finish)

reactor.run()
wb.save("IALOL.xls")
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.  Keep using `getPage` and tell it to **POST** instead of **GET** or use `Agent`.

The [API documentation for `getPage`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html) directs you to the [API documentation for `HTTPClientFactory`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.HTTPClientFactory.html) to discover additional supported options.

The latter API documentation explicitly covers `method` and implies (but does a bad job of explaining) `postdata`.  So, to make a **POST** with `getPage`:

```
d = getPage(url, method='POST', postdata="hello, world, or whatever.")
```

There is a [howto-style document for `Agent`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) (linked from the [overall web howto documentation index](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/).  This gives examples of sending a request with a body (ie, see the `FileBodyProducer` example).

Comment: Hey Jean-Paul Calderone, thank you VERY MUCH for your answer ! That helps a lot ! 
Little problem for you :) : With your solution implemented here : http://pastebin.com/Xk9GSmvR I get this error : http://pastebin.com/1b7ahvx6

If you can help me a last time to figure out why ... You're gonna be my lord ;)

Comment: EDIT: Maybe I get "Failure: exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 6: expected string, dict found" because for "postdata", I'm putting strange thing instead of a string  ?

Comment: Probably.  The value for `postdata` must be of type `str`.